# How to create private BlueSpice for MediaWiki website?

Tags: mediawiki, permissions

I am creating a private wiki that should only be visible to users that sign in.  We are using MediaWiki with the BlueSpice extension.  Thus far, I found that by default "read" access is provided to everyone, logged in or not.  Therefore, I explicitly added read access in the `WikiAdmin - Permission manager` to group `User` checking for line `Read` the `Namespace` column. Having done this, the pages now say:

```
Login required
Please log in to view other pages.
```

So this is good, however, there are still details visible.  For example, the special page `http://wiki.domain.com/index.php/Special:RecentChanges` shows the names of pages and the log entry for each edit.  Additionally, the names of users are revealed and their edit history.

How can I make the site hidden so that only authorized logged in Users can get information from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to go to group `*` in the `WikiAdmin - Permission manager` and uncheck the `Read` under the `Wiki` column adjacent to the `Namespace` column mentioned in the question.