# How to allow MediaWiki non-users to only read some wiki pages related login and account creation?

Tags: mediawiki, authentication, permissions

I've created a BlueSpice MediaWiki site that I only want visible to users that are logged in.  This works fine by creating Read permission only for Users as described [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/77057/49686).

All this works fine until I try and add two-factor authentication, which when logging in, goes to a second page to get the token at http://wiki.domain.com/index.php/Special:TwoFactorAuth/auth but this page fails to load due to no read permission:

> Please log in to view other pages.

So how can I make this one page special and readable by all?

A similar issue exists for the special page http://wiki.domain.com/index.php/Special:RequestAccount that gets added with the [ConfirmAccount extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount), so more generally, a set of special pages needs to be readable when not logged in, and the remaining that show information such as page names and user names should not be readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [wgWhitelistRead](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgWhitelistRead) in your `LocalSettings.php` configuration file.